# Who coined the term "immune system"?

Tags: terminology, biology, medicine

Who coined the term "immune system"?

The *OED* lists the following as its earliest example of the term "[immune system](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/91999#eid117080817)":

> [1943   *Science* 30 Apr. 406/1](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/97/2522/405.full.pdf)
> Complement..is removed by the addition of an antigen and the corresponding rabbit antibody unrelated to the immune system to be analysed.

Comment: Here is [Immunsystem](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=uc1.b2954030&num=734) used in 1909 by [Schultz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Schultz), quoting Manwaring ([1907](https://books.google.com/books?id=XxcfAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA743)) which however doesn’t seem to use the expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translated from G. Toepfer, *Historisches Wörterbuch der Biologie* (2016), vol. 3, [pp. 226–227](https://books.google.com/books?id=nvrZDAAAQBAJ&ots=IyL4bECHSI&pg=PA227&dq=Immunsystem):

> ***Immune system***
>
> (...) The discovery of a specific ***immune system*** in vertebrates took place in the 20th century.<sup>89</sup> The immune system concept was already used sporadically in the first decades of the 20th century. Thus in 1909 E. Meyer and E. Emmerich reported their investigation of a “bacteriolytic immune system”<sup>90</sup> and in 1920 H. Schade spoke of the “hemolytic immune system, consisting of blood cells and associated hemolysin-amboceptor”.<sup>91</sup> But until the 1950s, the expression covered primarily laboratory investigated defense reactions, viz. the reaction system of antigens and antibodies<sup>92</sup> — the expression only solidified into the concept of a body’s defense system in the mid-60s, first under the name *lymphoid system*,<sup>93</sup> but soon thereafter as “immune system”.<sup>94</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>**89** Cf. Moulin, A. M. ([1989](http://www.jstor.org/stable/23330349)). The immune system: a key concept for the history of immunology. Hist. Philos. Life Sci. 11, 221–236.
>
>   **90** Meyer, E. & Emmerich, E. ([1909](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=uc1.b3745906&num=305)). Über paroxysmale Hämoglobinurie. Deutsches Archiv für klinische Medizin 96, 287–327: 305.
>
>   **91** Schade, H. (1920). Die physikalische Chemie in der inneren Medizin: 135; cf. 2nd ed. (1923): 142.
>
>   **92** Bier, O. G., Siqueira, M. & Osler, A. G. (1955). Studies on the mechanism of hypersensitivity phenomena 1. Internat. Arch. Allergy Appl. Immunol. 7, 1–9: 5.
>
>   **93** Cooper, M. D., Peterson, R. D. & Good, R. A. (1965). Delineation of the thymic and lymphoid system in the chicken. Nature 205, 143; (...)
>
>   **94** New York Times, 24 Oct. 1965: IV. 8/3 (after OED).</sup>